# Retrieve query string from Kendo Window Content URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I am having an issue retrieving URL query strings. Say, in one HTML page I have a button. When the button is pressed, I call some javascript function like this.

```
function() {
    $("#kendowindow").kendoWindow ({
        width: 50%,
        height: 50%,
        content: "page.html?querystring=2&secondquerystring=3"
    }),
}
```

Now, in page.html, I want to retrieve both query string values and use them in another javascript function. Is there any way I can do this?

page.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Kendo Window Page </h1>
    </body>
    <script>
        alert(window.location); // This displays my first page url (NOT page.html?querystring=2&secondquerystring=3)
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can retrieve query string values from the content property of a kendo window? I need them for a separate javascript function defined in page.html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @user3781214, are you got the solution of your issue, I m working on kendo asp.net core, but I want to set the logic same as you want and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see it is because `page.html` is not loaded inside an `iframe` and as consequence it does not have its own `url` (KendoUI loads the content of the page inside the DOM of the same page).

You have two options:

1. Load it as an `iframe` adding `iframe: true` to the `kendoWindow` options
2. Access the KendoUI window from the inner code and ask for the `content` option.

Option 1:

KendoUI Window creation code

```
$("#kendowindow").kendoWindow({
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    content: "page.html?querystring=2&secondquerystring=3",
    iframe: true
});
```

and the page HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Kendo Window Page </h1>
    </body>
    <script>
        console.log("url", window.location.href);
    </script>
</html>
```

Option 2:

KendoUI Window creation code:

```
$("#kendowindow").kendoWindow({
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    content: "page.html?querystring=2&secondquerystring=3"
});
```

and the page HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Kendo Window Page </h1>
    </body>
    <script>
        var win = $("#kendowindow").data("kendoWindow");
        console.log("url", win.options.content.url);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to make changes to page.html. For some reason, I'm not seeing any changes. Are the kendo windows cached or something? For instance, if I change <h1> to "Updated Title", I don't see the change reflected when I open a window.

Comment: I don't think that KendoUI is caching your page, maybe your browser or the web/application server where you deploy it. What about if you open the page directly in the browser, do you see that change in the `<h1>`?

Comment: Yes, I see the change if I open it directly in the browser. I'm not seeing the change in the window though when I set iframe = true. If I remove this property, then I see the updated window. However, then removing the iframe property will cause both of your suggested answers to not work. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: In _option 2_ solution, what does it show as `url` in the `console`? Does it show any error?

Comment: Yes, $ is undefined (var win = $("#kendowindow").data("kendoWindow");)

Comment: After I launched it in the browser, and then tried reloading a kendo window, I get this: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference

Comment: If `$` is undefined in *option 2* means that you are actually loading it as an `iframe` (!?). Could you try in *option 2* to force `iframe` to `false`?